# My C++ program crashes when trying to output data read from a file

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program that stores a database of employees and stores them in an external file.  the function that reads a vector from the .dat file and loads it into the program reads the file but whenever I try to display or modify the  loaded vector the program crashes.

```
//displays vector
void Database:: displayAll() const
{
    for(std::vector<Employee>::const_iterator iter = mEmployees.begin(); iter != mEmployees.end(); ++iter)
    {
        iter -> display();
    }

}

std::vector<Employee> mEmployees;

void Database::readData()
{
    ifstream empIn("employee.dat" , ios::binary);
    empIn.seekg(0,ifstream::end);
    long size2 = empIn.tellg();
    empIn.seekg(0,ifstream::beg);
    mEmployees.resize(size2);
    empIn.read((char*)&mEmployees, size2);
    empIn.close();
    cout << mEmployees.size() << endl; //this tests whether or not it reads.
}
```

Comment: Are you by any change introducing the same bug in the code that writes the data? Note that any data you have written so far with the bugged code would be unusable (as you would have actually written a bunch of random bytes)

Answer (score 3):

You haven't showed us your declaration of `mEmployees`, but I assume its a `std::vector` of some kind. The problem is that you are trying to read the file into the `vector` object, instead of into its content. That will corrupt the `vector`, as well as any other memory next to it, causing crashes further on.

What you probably want instead is:

```
empIn.read((char*)&mEmployees[0], size2);
```

or in **C++11**:

```
empIn.read((char*)mEmployees.data(), size2);
```

to actually read the *contents* of the file into the *contents* of the `vector`.

To understand why this is happening, you should know that the *contents* of a `vector` are not stored within the `vector` itself *(how could they? the size is dynamic)*. Instead, a common implementation of `vector` has pointers to the begin and end of a storage area, somewhere in the free store, where the contents are actually held. When you try to read a file into the memory layout of the `vector` you are overwriting those pointers, as well as memory beyond the `vector` itself, corrupting the vector among other things.

Answer (score 0):

The cast to `(char*)` tells the compiler to discard the type-checking that it would normally do.  It is necessary to perform the cast in this case since `ifstream` requires you to pass a `char*`.  The problem is, this `reinterpret_cast` is a rather blunt instrument and fails to warn  you that you are converting from a `vector<Employee>*` when you intended to convert from an `Employee*`.

Just remember that casts like this are low-level operations whose purpose is to tell the compiler that "you know what you are doing, even though it seems wrong".  They should be used with extra care.

A better, and corrected, form for what you are doing would be:

```
empIn.read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&mEmployees[0]), mEmployees.size() );
```

Comment: i tried this and it stopped my program from crashing but when i called the function to display the contents of the vector it only displayed a random bunch of characters.

Comment: @aceassasin: You haven't shown the code which attempts to show the contents.  Normally, this would have to display the contents of mEmployee one field at a time and one record at a time.